# How to deal with escape characters with JSON loads?

Tags: python, json, escaping

```
search = """
[{"text":"Dolores Keane - \"Craigie Hills\" (1982)"}]
"""
print(loads(search)) # Returns Error
print(search.replace('"',"'")) # Turns all double quotes to single quotes, both the escaped and non escaped ones
```

Here's my issues: I just don't know how to load this sort of strings into JSON. Any tips? I tried a billion things. Tried repr(search), etc, nothing works.

EDIT: For those who wonder about the question: the issue is that the string has both double quotes that indicate a dictionary item or key (") and double quotes with a backslash before them that indicate part of a string ("). I was not able to load the string, correctly differentiating between the two.

In the answers, I got two solutions: using a rawstring, and dumping before loading.

The error:
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 2 column 28 (char 28)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to escape the `\` so that you *have* literal backslashes in the JSON. Use a raw string literal

```
search = r"""
[{"text":"Dolores Keane - \"Craigie Hills\" (1982)"}]
"""
```

or let `json.dumps` produce the JSON in the first place:

```
search = json.dumps([dict(text='Dolores Keane - "Craigie Hills" (1982)'}])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double backslahes to escape quotes in the json:

```
search = """
[{"text":"Dolores Keane - \\"Craigie Hills\\" (1982)"}]
"""
```

or raw string literal:

```
search = r"""
[{"text":"Dolores Keane - \"Craigie Hills\" (1982)"}]
"""
```

Comment: The  string will come from internet, so double backslash is no option. But the raw string worked, in combination with json dumps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json.dumps` to see how the original object should be encoded into JSON:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps([{"text":"Dolores Keane - \"Craigie Hills\" (1982)"}])
'[{"text": "Dolores Keane - \\"Craigie Hills\\" (1982)"}]'
```

and then confirm that `json.loads` can decode that same string:

```
>>> search = json.dumps([{"text":"Dolores Keane - \"Craigie Hills\" (1982)"}])
>>> json.loads(search)
[{'text': 'Dolores Keane - "Craigie Hills" (1982)'}]
```